# How to understand the "blessed" of "new things that have yet to be blessed" here?

Tags: word-meaning

The whole context (from *Learning OpenCV Computer Vision in C++ with the OpenCV Library (Early Release)*):

> Here are the current modules:
>
> ...
>
> contrib: This module contains new
>   things that have yet to be **blessed** into the whole of the library.
>
> legacy: This module contains old things that have yet to be banished
>   from the library altogether.
>
> ...

I can understand the sentence like "God bless you", but how to understand the code is blessed? who blessed the code? and what is the meaning of something blessed into something?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392135/what-exactly-does-perls-bless-do

Comment: @DamkerngT. Interesting. But in that SO post they didn't explain the meaning of bless in semantic.

Comment: When someone said *bless* and *banish* in the context of programming, I'd guess that they've worked with Perl before. I think the author of the excerpt used that kind of lingo. I could be wrong in details, but I don't think I was very far off.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'm confused with the `yet` there. Does it mean: up to now, these new things are not included by other module so blessed into the `contrib` module?

Comment: Ahh... that *yet* could be another question! But I think this definition could help: [have yet to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/have-yet-to-do-something): used for saying that something has not happened or been done up to the present time, especially when you think it should have happened or been done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I've sort of answered in the comments (even though I didn't intend to at first), I think I should wrap those up as an answer.

Judging from the context, which is a programming context, I believe that the author uses those words because they're understandable among programmers. (For more background of *bless*, which is related to the Perl programming language, check out [What exactly does Perl's “bless” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392135/what-exactly-does-perls-bless-do) And *bless* basically means to associate a reference with a package.)

We can understand these two words like this:

> ***blessed into*** = put into, included in
>   ***banished from*** = removed/excluded from

As to "who blessed the code?", it would be whoever is responsible for the maintenance of the code base.